# How do I send XMR to Binance?

Tags: binance

I am looking to send xmr to binance, any one who have already done this, it will be really helpful for me.

Comment: Please see the question I linked. You have to take their address and add it as recipient on the `Send` page. In addition, you have to 'activate' the long payment IDs feature and subsequently add the long payment ID Binance provided (on the `Send` page). Let me know if you need any further assistance.